# How to apply join only for particular section of an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm getting an array and strigifying it in this array variable:

```
let arrayStr = oldArr.join(', ');
```

My array looks like this in console:

```
(a), text1, (b), text2, (c), text3, (d), text3
```

What I want is to make it look like this:

```
(a) - text1, (b) - text2, (c) - text3, (d) - text3
```

I know that I've added `', '` after all strings, but how can I apply it like above?

Thanks.

Comment: So your input array is like this: `['(a)', 'text1', '(b)', 'text2', '(c)', 'text3', '(d)', 'text3']` is that correct?

Comment: El correcto! :) Only it's strigified.

Comment: Ok - I added an answer for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by looping through the array and accessing the current item and also the following one by its index and then appending both to the same element of a new array, something like this:

```js
var oldArr = ['(a)', 'text1', '(b)', 'text2', '(c)', 'text3', '(d)', 'text3'];

var newArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < oldArr.length; i++) {
  newArr.push(oldArr[i] + ' - ' + oldArr[++i]);
}

console.log(newArr.join(', '));
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try please. Also, is there a way this can be achieved inside of the join() ?

Comment: Unfortunately not as `join()` only accepts a single string with which to join all array elements together. It doesn't take any other logic.

Comment: No, after calling `join()` you have a string. That can't be joined again

Comment: I need it as a string, as I need to show it in one <td></td>

Answer (score 1):

You could use a three step solution, first get all items who are connected in a single sub array, map the joinded sub arrays and joun the outer array.

```js
var array = ['(a)', 'text1', '(b)', 'text2', '(c)', 'text3', '(d)', 'text3'],
    text = array
        .reduce(function (r, a, i) {
            i % 2 ? r[r.length - 1].push(a) : r.push([a]) ;
            return r;
        }, [])
        .map(function (a) {
            return a.join(' - ');
        })
        .join(', ');

console.log(text);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina, it's working great, but I'm going to accept Rory's solution as he was a bit faster.

Comment: faster is not a criterium for accepting. it's just the question, which answers fits better your need.

Comment: Fair enough, I've felt a need to explain myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the array elements and make use of `%`(modulo) operator to combine the values as you need:

```js
var oldArr = ['(a)', 'text1', '(b)', 'text2', '(c)', 'text3', '(d)', 'text4'];
var arrayStr  = [];
for (var i = 0; i < oldArr.length; i++) {
  if (i % 2 != 0) {
    oldArr[i] = oldArr[i - 1] + ' - ' + oldArr[i] ;
    arrayStr.push(oldArr[i]);
  }
}
console.log(arrayStr.join(', '));
```