# Apply color to only part of an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm going to reproduce an array from [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855219/how-to-apply-join-only-for-particular-section-of-an-array) for this:

```
console.log(arrayStr);
```

which outputs:

```
(a) - text1, (b) - text2, (c) - text3, (d) - text3
```

How can I apply a color to `(a) (b)`, etc. parts?

The regex would be: `/\([^)]+\)/g;`

Thanks.

Comment: To apply different colours to the HTML output you'd need to wrap those areas in their own element, ie a `span`, and apply CSS to those spans

Comment: That's a great solution. Can you please provide with the logic? Thanks @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: I added an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can expand your regex to capture a group. You can then use that to wrap the matched `(X)` values in `span` elements to which you can apply some CSS. Try this:

```js
$('div').html(function(i, html) {
  return html.replace(/(\([^)]+\))/g, "<span>$1</span>");
})
```

```css
span { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>(a) - text1, (b) - text2, (c) - text3, (d) - text3</div>
```

Here's a native JS implementation:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('foo');
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/(\([^)]+\))/g, "<span>$1</span>");
```

```css
span { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">(a) - text1, (b) - text2, (c) - text3, (d) - text3</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. What is $1 ? And how can this be done with plain js? Thanks.

Comment: `$1` is the first group matched by the Regular Expression.  I updated the answer to include a native implementation

Comment: You need to expand the regex to include an extra set of `()` as I mentioned above.